# sort values of an orddict

Tags: sorting, erlang, hashtable

In order to extract the values (records) of an orddict as a sorted list, tried this:

```
-module(test).
-compile(export_all).
-record(node, {name="", cost=0}).

test() ->
    List = orddict:append("A",#node{name="A",cost=1},
                          orddict:append("B",#node{name="B",cost=2},
                                         orddict:new())),
    lists:sort(fun({_,A},{_,B}) -> A#node.cost =< B#node.cost end,
               orddict:to_list(List)).
```

The sort fails with `exception error: {badrecord,node}`.
What would be the correct syntax?

## Solved:

The correct insertion method is `orddict:store/2` instead of `orddict:append/2`. Then the pattern `{_,A}` matches for the comparison function.

Comment: Just wondering why you wish to sort the orddict as it is already sorted?

Comment: the goal was to extract and sort the values of the orddict (which happened to be records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
lists:sort(fun({_,[A]},{_,[B]}) -> A#node.cost =< B#node.cost end,
               orddict:to_list(List)).
```

I not found note about this in documentation,but you can look in [source code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/86d1fb0865193cce4e308baa6472885a81033f10/lib/stdlib/src/orddict.erl#L126) of module.

As @Pascal write in comments the reason is that [orddict:append/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/orddict.html#append-3) is a function provided to append a value to an existing Key/Value pair where Value must be a list. In the use case, the key doesn't exist, so the pair is created and the Value append to an empty list.

Btw, you always can print and compare real and expected result.

```
io:format("~p~n",[orddict:to_list(List)])
```

For your example that is:

```
[{"A",[{node,"A",1}]},{"B",[{node,"B",2}]}]
```

Comment: The reason is that `orddict:append/3` is a function provided to append a value to an existing Key/Value pair where Value must be a list. In the use case, the key doesn't exist, so the pair is created and the Value append to an empty list